# User form not updating and not showing any error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In this I am trying to update users form with inputs. But after submitting forms doesn't gets updated & shows older data in it.

vb code

```
Private Sub updateInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles updateInfo.Click
        Try
            Dim con As New MySqlConnection
            Dim query As New MySqlCommand
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString()
            query.Connection = con
            con.Open()
            query.CommandText = "UPDATE hospitals SET name = '" & businessName.Text & "', contactPerson = '" + contactPerson.Text + "', websiteName = '" + websiteName.Text + "', email = '" + emailName.Text + "', phone1 = '" + phone1.Text + "', phone2 = '" + phone2.Text + "', mobileNumber = '" + mobile.Text + "', buildingName = '" + buildingName.Text + "', streetName = '" + address.Text + "', landmark = '" + landmark.Text + "', areaName = '" + areaName.Text + "', city = '" + suburb.Text + "', state = '" + state.Text + "', zipCode = '" + zip.Text + "', overview = '" + overview.Text + "', registration = '" + regNo.Text + "', establishment = '" + foundation.Text + "', founder = '" + founderName.Text + "', generalBed = '" + GeneralBeds.Text + "', icuBed = '" + ICU.Text + "', consultancyFees = '" + consultinfees.Text + "', mondayFrom = '" + mondayFrom.Text + "', mondayTo = '" + mondayTo.Text + "', tuesdayFrom = '" + tuesdayFrom.Text + "', tuesdayTo = '" + tuesdayTo.Text + "', wednesdayFrom = '" + wedFrom.Text + "', wednesdayTo = '" + wedTo.Text + "', thursdayFrom = '" + thursdayFrom.Text + "', thursdayTo = '" + thursdayTo.Text + "', fridayFrom = '" + fridayFrom.Text + "', fridayTo = '" + fridayTo.Text + "', saturdayFrom = '" + saturdayFrom.Text + "', saturdayTo = '" + saturdayTo.Text + "', sundayFrom = '" + sundayFrom.Text + "', sundayTo = '" + sundayTo.Text + "', visitFrom = '" + visitFrom.Text + "', visitTo = '" + visitTo.Text + "', bestKnownFor = '" + bestknowFor.Text + "' WHERE hospitalID = '" & TextId.Text + "'"
            query.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con.Close()
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('Information updated successfully.');</script>")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

hence it's not showing any error as well. Please help to identify problem.

UPDATE

```
 If IsPostBack Then
            Try
                Dim str As String = "SELECT * FROM  hospitals WHERE username='" + Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("chkusername").Value) + "';"
                con.Open()
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(str, con)
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim lblservice As New Label
                For Each chk As ListItem In servicesList.Items
                    If chk.Selected = True Then
                        lblservice.Text = String.Concat(lblservice.Text + ",", chk.Value)

                    End If
                Next

                da.Fill(dt)
                con.Close()
                TextId.Text = dt.Rows(0)("hospitalID").ToString
                businessName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("name").ToString
                welcome.Text = dt.Rows(0)("name").ToString
                subCat.Text = dt.Rows(0)("subcategory").ToString
                contactPerson.Text = dt.Rows(0)("contactPerson").ToString
                websiteName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("websiteName").ToString
                emailName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("email").ToString
                phone1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("phone1").ToString
                phone2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("phone2").ToString
                mobile.Text = dt.Rows(0)("mobileNumber").ToString
                buildingName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("buildingName").ToString
                address.Text = dt.Rows(0)("streetName").ToString
                landmark.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Landmark").ToString
                areaName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("areaName").ToString
                suburb.Text = dt.Rows(0)("city").ToString
                state.Text = dt.Rows(0)("state").ToString
                zip.Text = dt.Rows(0)("zipCode").ToString
                overview.Text = dt.Rows(0)("overview").ToString
                regNo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("registration").ToString
                foundation.Text = dt.Rows(0)("establishment").ToString
                founderName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Founder").ToString
                GeneralBeds.Text = dt.Rows(0)("generalBed").ToString
                ICU.Text = dt.Rows(0)("icuBed").ToString
                consultinfees.Text = dt.Rows(0)("consultancyFees").ToString
                mondayFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("mondayFrom").ToString
                mondayTo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("mondayTo").ToString
                tuesdayFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("tuesdayFrom").ToString
                tuesdayTo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("tuesdayTo").ToString
                wedFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("wednesdayFrom").ToString
                wedTo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("wednesdayTo").ToString
                thursdayFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("thursdayFrom").ToString
                thursdayFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("thursdayFrom").ToString
                fridayFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("fridayFrom").ToString
                fridayTo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("fridayTo").ToString
                saturdayFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("saturdayFrom").ToString
                saturdayTo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("saturdayTo").ToString
                sundayFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("sundayFrom").ToString
                sundayTo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("sundayTo").ToString
                visitFrom.Text = dt.Rows(0)("visitFrom").ToString
                visitTo.Text = dt.Rows(0)("visitTo").ToString
                bestknowFor.Text = dt.Rows(0)("bestKnownFor").ToString

            Catch ex As Exception
                Response.Write(ex)
            End Try
        End If
```

Comment: why you use *&* first, and then *+*?

Comment: @Khazratbek sorry. that might by mistake. But is that the reason for not updating?

Comment: Try to put breakpoint in the line of your query and see the full query: is it correct or not. If not, find mistake and fix it

Comment: I would add a breakpoint after the query.CommandText to see what it looks like prior to the Execute.  Also assign query.ExecuteNonQuery() to a new variable to see what the result is, if it's greater than 0, something is getting updated.

Comment: @Khazratbek in my page first  onload I am getting the values in to the from database. Ans as I put breakpoint in my update query It doesn't shows me the updated value of a field I changed. It shows that value which is already present

Comment: Naturally, it won't. You have to load your database inside *if (!IsPostBack)*. As you could see, before *OnClick* works, your values from Database come again and it overrides it's new values. Just pust your work with database on page load into checking

Comment: @Khazratbek please post example as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string item_id = "-1";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        item_id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        RestoreItemData(item_id);
    }
}

protected void RestoreItemData(string id)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utils.Connection);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("items_sel", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        sdr.Read();
        txtName.Text = sdr["name"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utils.Connection);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("items_iu", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item_id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtName.Text.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@supitem_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Session["supitem"].ToString();

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Items_list.aspx");
    }
}

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Utils.Connection);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("items_d", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = item_id;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Items_list.aspx");
    }
}
```

It is just an example, as you requested.
Let me explain. When it is initial page load, block *if (!IsPostBack)* will be executed first.

Let me give you an example. You have a list of hospitals. When you click on any hospital, detail information about hospital should be displayed, and you have to be able to modify data by request.

So what will *if (!IsPostBack)* do?

Let's imagine that your hospital has just one column: *name*, and you have some string variable called *hospital_name*. And let me give you all occuring steps in your solution... You have some hospital called *Virginia*. Your solution do:

1) *hospital_name* = "Virginia";

2) You are updating it is name to "Virginia1". So *hospital_name* = "Virginia1" now. And you click on button

3) Your page_load occurs first and now *hospital_name* = "Virginia" again, caz' it's from database

4) Your button_click method fires, but updating values to the old.

So if you will move retrieving from a database inside PostBack, flow is as follows:

1) *hospital_name* = "Virginia"

2) you change it's value: *hospital_name* = "Virginia1"

3) Your page_load fires, but retrieving from database is inside *if (!IsPostBack)*, but button's click will fire postback, so retrieving from database will not work here. So your *hospital_name* still equal to "Virginia1"

4) button click method fires and change your database's value to the "Virginia1"

Hope you understand this.

Comment: Sorry but some how I am getting confused in this. Please see updated post. I have updated page load event.

Comment: *IsPostBack* -> *!IsPostBack*

Comment: onload existing value doesn't display with this